# Ajax busca de Endereço com PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho um formulário com a lista de clientes.
Ao selecionar o cliente, quero que preencha automaticamente os campos de endereço, numero, bairro e cidade.

Tenho o Ajax, mas não sei como elaborar o retorno dele.

```
var id = $('#cliente').val();

$.ajax(
    {
        url:"ajax/endereco/" + id,
        success:function(result) {
            $('[name="servicos[0].endereco"]').val(result.endereco);
            $('[name="servicos[0].numero"]').val(result.numero);
            $('[name="servicos[0].bairro"]').val(result.bairro);
            $('[name="servicos[0].cidade"]').val(result.cidade);
        }
    }
);
```

Gostaria de saber como conseguir importar os dados que vem desse endereço... ou como exibir os dados, como seria o PHP dele? Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: O que te dá `success:function(result) { console.log(result);` ?

Comment: Não imprime nada. Mas se eu der um alert(id), ele vai imprimir o ID que passo pra ele... oque eu não estou sabendo desenvolver, é o PHP, que exibe estes resultados...

Comment: Já tens alguma coisa no PHP? como é a query que estás a fazer?

Comment: Não... na verdade, eu montei o módulo agora do Ajax... pra ver se eu consigo chegar neste resultado... Mas não tenho nem idéia de como colocar no codeigniter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu ajax ta certo só precisa adicionar umas coisas

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url:"ajax/endereco/id/" + id,',
    async: false,
    success:function(d){
        result = JSON.parse(d);
        $('[name="servicos[0].endereco"]').val(result.endereco);
        $('[name="servicos[0].numero"]').val(result.numero);
        $('[name="servicos[0].bairro"]').val(result.bairro);
        $('[name="servicos[0].cidade"]').val(result.cidade);
    }
});
```

Normalmente eu uso `async: false` nesse tipo de requisição para ter certeza que só vai tentar colocar as informações nos campos depois que elas forem retornadas.

E o PHP fica assim

```
public function suaFuncao(){
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $conect = "parametros de conexão com o banco ";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = $id";
    $result = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($conect, $sql));
    echo json_encode($result); exit;
```

}

O PHP é bem simples, você só pega o id que esta vindo por parâmetro e usa ele na sua `query`, o resultado você retorna dando um `json_encode`

Comment: Não consegui.. nem instalar o módulo de ajax... vou pensar mais a respeito